# Customized listview

Tags: android, listview

I have in my android application a listview.
I have 3 images should be used as BG.
1 for the list top - with top rounded edges
1 for the buttom list - with buttom rounded edgest
1 for middle - sharp edges.

How can I use these as BG?

Yoav

Comment: Custom ListView in Android Tutorial : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/770/create-custom-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you want to have a custom layout for the first and the last item of your listview, and all the other elements will have the same layout? Right?

Maybe you should read this: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Most important code is here:

```
if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_FIRST_OR_LAST_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
```